# How do I make a smart contract on MyEtherWallet?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

I've tried downloading the Ethereum wallet but it's taken weeks to download blocks. The only other option is MyEtherWallet. I asked on Reddit someone said theirs a way to do it with MyEtherWallet and MetaMask but I need to know exactly how to do it.

Any online tutorials or detailed explanations on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** use browser solidity http://remix.ethereum.org for writing and testing smart contract.

When you are using Ethereum wallet, you are actually connecting to either ethereum mainnet or testnet. For development and learning purpose the best solution is to create private Ethereum network. You can find a lot of tutorials online. [Here](https://github.com/manojpramesh/eth-doc/blob/master/private-network.md) is the one I created for my personal use.

Create a private network of your own and then connect the wallet to that network or use the Web3js javascript console(recommended) to deploy your contracts to the network. This [tutorial](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API) will help you get started with web3js.

Answer (score 0):

Few options here:

1. Deploy using parity. Warp sync should take [less than an hour](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/issues/6372#issuecomment-369402411).

You should be able to start a production node that both listens to RPC and provides UI via:

```
parity —geth —chain ropsten —force-ui —jsonrpc-cors
```

If you wish to experiment with a test network I recommend doing that first. Here's how to start a node that automatically unlocks a wallet for easier testing:

```
parity —geth —chain ropsten —force-ui —jsonrpc-cors http://localhost —reseal-min-period 0 —unlock 0x00... —password ./path-to-password-file.txt
```

2. Deploy using an Infura node

   You can interact with Infura nodes both via RPC and HTTP calls. Here's the [official documentation](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/using-infura-custom-provider) and an independent tutorial on [how to deploy a contract using Truffle](http://www.masonforest.com/blockchain/ethereum/2017/11/13/how-to-deploy-an-erc20-token-in-20-minutes.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need `bytecode` of contract ro be deployed. You can remix to get bytecode.

- Paste you contract code in remix editor
- Click on the details tab
- Under `BYTECODE` section copy the data under objects section.
- Copy bytecode from there
- Open MEW--> COntracts Tab--> Deploy Contract
- Paste the bytecode there
- The gas will be filled automatically. It is recommended not to change that
- Choose the account from which you want to deploy
- Send Tx. Once Tx is mined, your contract is created.

**Note:** This was for contracts without constructor params. If your contract has constructor params you need to do little more. Check out my medium post [Deploying contract using byteCode](https://medium.com/@prashantprabhakarsingh/deploying-contract-using-bytecode-myetherwallet-and-remix-10f643a82d40)

Answer (score -1):

### You cannot create contracts in MEW

However if you connect MEW to your `local tesetnet` or `testrpc` and deploy the contract there, you can use [MEW interface](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts) to contract with contract.

Comment: This is not correct. You can deploy contracts using bytecode